# relation $L_{\infty}$ and bounded function

Tags: real-analysis

Is that right?
$$f\in L_{\infty}([a,b]) ~\Rightarrow~ |f|<\infty \text{ on }[a,b]$$ 
Under what conditions is that equivalent?

Comment: I think they are equivalent.

Comment: If $f$ is measurable, $f\in L_\infty$ if and only if there is an $M$ such that $|f|<M$ off a set of measure zero. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces).

Answer (score 0):

This implication is not true in general, the other one is not, either. For example, $f(x)=1/(x-a)$ for $x>a$, $f(a)=0$ satisfies the right hand side. On the other hand, $g(x)=0$ for $x<b$, $g(b)=\infty$ satisfies only the left hand side.

The two are trivially equivalent for continuous functions (both sides are always satisfied), but this is already false for pointwise limits of continuous functions (since $g(x)$ is the limit of $nx^n$ for $a=0,b=1$).

A somewhat nontrivial equivalence holds for continous functions into extended reals, like $f(x)=1/(x-a)$ for $x>a$, $f(a)=\infty$.